# Association tables with multiple foreign-key relationships on one column in SQLAlchemy + SQLite

Tags: python, sqlite, sqlalchemy

**tldr;** In the SQLAlchemy ORM Mapper class [docs](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many), an example is provided for how to create association tables many-to-many relationship between two tables, like so:

[image: association table with one parent and one child]

But how can I create a many-to-many association with four parent tables and a single child table? In the E/R diagram below, `keyword`, `solution`,`pattern`, and `question` are the parent tables, `data_lineage_lookup` is the association table, and `data_lineage` is the child table.

[image: association table with four parents and one child]

---

**Background info:** I have three tables in my database to organize data lineage metadata. The first table, `data_lineage_lookup`, is an association table (many-to-many) where the `id` column has foreign-key relationships with four other tables: `question`, `solution`,`pattern`, and `keyword`. In `data_lineage_lookup`, each id in the `id` column is unique. Each such `id` is paired with a `data_lineage_id`.

The `data_lineage_id` is a foreign key to the `data_lineage` table, which holds metadata about where the data was sourced from in the form of json documents kept in the `json_body` column.

Additionally, each json document in the `data_lineage` table has a corresponding `json_schema` (many-to-one relationship where many documents share the same [json schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/))

```sql
-- association table I would like to recreate
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_lineage_lookup (
    id TEXT NOT NULL, 
    data_lineage_id TEXT NOT NULL, 
        -- text id's of any kind can be used to look up data lineage
        FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES question (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES solution (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES pattern  (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (id) REFERENCES keyword  (id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
        FOREIGN KEY (data_lineage_id) REFERENCES data_lineage  (id) ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS data_lineage (
    id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (lower(hex(randomblob(4)))),
    json_schema_id INTEGER NOT NULL,
    json_body         TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_found_timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL,
        FOREIGN KEY (json_schema_id) REFERENCES json_schema (id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS json_schema (
    id TEXT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY DEFAULT (lower(hex(randomblob(4)))),
    title                   TEXT NOT NULL,
    body                    TEXT NOT NULL,
    date_added_timestamp INTEGER NOT NULL
);
```

**The question:** According to the documentation on [many-to-many relationships in ORM mapper classes](https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/basic_relationships.html#many-to-many),  the following example serves to illustrate how to use an association table and `relationship()` columns to establish a many-to-many relationship, but here the association table has two columns – one for each table it associates with, and so the use of `relationship()` is straightforward.

```py
association_table = Table('association', Base.metadata,
    Column('left_id', ForeignKey('left.id')),
    Column('right_id', ForeignKey('right.id'))
)

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'left'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relationship("Child",
                    secondary=association_table)

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'right'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
```

I've already declared the mapper classes below in SQLAlchemy, but How can I configure the `data_lineage_lookup.id` column so it serves as a single foreign-key column that map to 4 different tables: `question`, `solution`, `pattern`, and `keyword`  through a  `relationship()` in the `JsonSchema` ORM Mapper Class?

```py
'''
Document Metadata Schema
'''

@declarative_mixin
class DocumentMetadata:

    id = Column(Text, nullable=False, primary_key=True, default=text('(lower(hex(randomblob(4))))'), server_default=text('(lower(hex(randomblob(4))))'))
    body = Column(JSON, nullable=False) # TODO: check datatype after loading data with `select typeof(col) from table;`
    date_added = Column(DATETIME, nullable=False)

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"<{self.__class__.__name__}{self.__dict__}>"

    @declared_attr
    def __tablename__(cls):
        return re.sub(r'(?<!^)(?=[A-Z])', '_', cls.__name__).lower()


data_lineage_lookup = Table(
    'data_lineage_lookup',
    Base.metadata,
    Column('id',
        ForeignKey('question.id', ondelete="CASCADE"),
        ForeignKey('solution.id', ondelete="CASCADE"),
        ForeignKey('pattern.id', ondelete="CASCADE"),
        ForeignKey('keyword.id', ondelete="CASCADE")
    ),
    Column('data_lineage_id', ForeignKey('data_lineage.id', ondelete="CASCADE"))
)

class JsonSchema(Base, DocumentMetadata):
    title = Column(Text, nullable=False)

class DataLineage(Base, DocumentMetadata):
    json_schema_id = Column(Text, ForeignKey('json_schema.id', ondelete='RESTRICT'), nullable=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to simply treat the `keyword`, `question`, `pattern`, `solution` ORM mapper classes as parent tables, and the `data_lineage` ORM mapper like child tables, all of which share the same association table, `data_lineage_lookup`.

So the code for the association table looks like this:

```py
data_lineage_lookup = Table(
    'data_lineage_lookup',
    Base.metadata,
    Column(
        'id',
        ForeignKey('question.id', ondelete="CASCADE"),
        ForeignKey('solution.id', ondelete="CASCADE"),
        ForeignKey('pattern.id', ondelete="CASCADE"),
        ForeignKey('keyword.id', ondelete="CASCADE"),
        nullable=False
    ),
    Column('data_lineage_id', ForeignKey('data_lineage.id', ondelete="CASCADE"), nullable=False)
)
```

and each data ORM mapper class should have a `data_lineages` attribute as follows

```py
class Keyword(Base, Document):
    patterns = relationship(
        'Pattern',
        secondary=keyword_lookup,
        back_populates='keywords'
    )
    data_lineages = relationship( #<- like this
        'DataLineage', 
        secondary=data_lineage_lookup
    )
```